# String 'Electric' too long but datatype is set as VARCHAR(500)

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I"m getting an error and I'm stuck.

I've created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE filtered_derived_analytics.um_state_stats 
( 
    issued_but_not_imported integer, 
    imported_but_not_sent_to_apm integer, 
    in_apm_but_not_batched integer, 
    batched_but_not_approved integer, 
    approved_but_check_not_cut integer, 
    paid integer, 
    total integer, 
    collected_on date, 
    utility_type varchar(500),
    utility_company_name varchar(500),
    DATA OBJECT
) IF NOT EXISTS;
```

But when I try to insert data into that table using this:

```
SET current_schema =
  (SELECT LEFT("schema", 10) AS imported_at
   FROM PUBLIC.imports
   ORDER BY "schema" DESC
   LIMIT 1);


SELECT m.data_type AS utility_type,
       uc.name AS utility_company_name,
       COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM wegowise_meters m
LEFT JOIN wegowise_properties p ON p.meter_id = m.id
LEFT JOIN wegowise_users u ON p.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN wegowise_utility_companies uc ON m.utility_company_id = uc.id
WHERE u.username IN
    (SELECT wegowise_username
     FROM um_charter_customers)
  AND m.next_expected_datum_date < $current_schema
  AND m.closed = FALSE
  AND m.scope != 'VacantUnitMeter'
  AND m.apm_bill_creation_config_uuid IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY utility_type,
         utility_company_name;


MERGE INTO um_state_stats stats USING
  (SELECT *
   FROM table(RESULT_SCAN (LAST_QUERY_ID(-1)))) results ON stats.collected_on = $current_schema WHEN matched THEN
UPDATE
SET stats.utility_type = results.utility_type,
    stats.utility_company = results.utility_company_name,
    stats.issued_but_not_imported = results.COUNT WHEN NOT matched THEN
INSERT (utility_type,
        utility_company,
        issued_but_not_imported,
        DATA,
        collected_on)
VALUES (results.utility_type,
        results.utility_company_name,
        results.COUNT,
        OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(),
        $current_schema);
```

I'm getting an error saying that string 'electric' (in utility_type) is too long. I checked the values in utility_type and they're all very short:

```
Gas
Electric
Water
Oil
Steam
Solar
Oil4
Oil6
Trash
Propane
```

Any thoughts? What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the `SET current_schema` command is setting the schema to the one you expect it to? You could try removing that (somewhat questionable) line just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `DESCRIBE TABLE um_state_stats` before `MERGE INTO um_state_stats stats USING...`.  It's possible that that `MERGE` statement isn't using the `filtered_derived_analytics` schema which I assume it should be.

Equally you could prefix the table name with the schema name by changing `MERGE INTO um_state_stats stats USING...` to  `MERGE INTO filtered_derived_analytics.um_state_stats stats USING...`

(Although hopefully you got it sorted after 3 months anyway )